# Proxying UDP DNS traffic to a TCP backend service

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-vpc

I am creating a CoreDNS DNS server on Kubernetes that needs to listen for UDP traffic on port 53 using an AWS network load balancer.  I would like that traffic to be proxied to a Kubernetes service using TCP.

My current service looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: coredns
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/port: "9153"
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  labels:
    k8s-app: coredns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "CoreDNS"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: coredns
  type: NodePort   
  ports:
  - name: dns
    port: 5353
    targetPort: 5353
    nodePort: 30053
    protocol: UDP
  - name: dns-tcp
    port: 5053
    targetPort: 5053
    nodePort: 31053
    protocol: TCP
  - name: metrics
    port: 9153
    targetPort: 9153
    protocol: TCP
```

The network load balancer speaks to the cluster on the specified node ports, but the UDP listener times out when requesting zone data from the server.

when I `dig` for records, I am getting a timeout **unless** `+tcp` is specified in the dig.  The health checks from the load balancer to the port are returning healthy, and the TCP queries are returning as expected.

Ideally, my listener would accept both TCP and UDP traffic on port 53 at the load balancer and return either TCP or UDP traffic based on the initial protocol of the request.

Is there anything glaringly obvious I am missing as to why UDP traffic is not either making it to my cluster or returning a response?